# how to revert one single file of a commit with multiple files

Tags: git, egit

Assume that I have committed 5 files. After I have committed I have noticed that I need to undo changes on one file of these 5 files. Is this possible ? if not what is the best why to undo the changes on one file?

Comment: `git checkout hash_of_previous_commit -- name_of_file_to_undo` ?

Comment: @ChatterOne: i get error: pathspec 'SettingsPoint' did not match any file(s) known to git.. Is it mybe because my file to be undo contains blank? file name is SettingsPoint Mi.lounch

Comment: Most likely, try with either either a `\\` before the space or using double quotes around the filename.

Comment: I tried to escape using \ and also double quotes as I have read from other posts but it is not working for me

Answer (score 2):

Expanding (and with a little adjustment on his comment) from ChatterOne, if what you want to is amend the revision (and forget about the bad revision):

```
git checkout HEAD~ -- path-to-file
git commit --amend --no-edit # replace the revision that I just created with this new revision I'm creating
```